# mount and /proc/mounts showing different outputs

Tags: linux, mount, slackware

0

I have the following line in my /etc/fstab on three of my slackware servers:

```
tmpfs            /dev/shm         tmpfs       rw,nodev,nosuid,noexec 0   0
```

All three show the mount options correctly in /proc/mounts:

```
tmpfs /dev/shm tmpfs rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime 0 0
```

Two of them show the correct options with the mount command:

```
tmpfs on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw,nodev,nosuid,noexec)
```

The third one shows different options with the mount command:

```
tmpfs on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw)
```

The only difference is the third one is at runlevel 4 while the other two are at runlevel 3. Any ideas on why the third one is showing two different mount options and which one is the correct one?

Comment: Is `/etc/mtab` a regular file (that would be updated by the `mount` command) or a symlink to `/proc/mounts`?

Comment: /etc/mtab is a regular file that is updated with the mount command.  It is correctly shown if I manually mount it with: "mount -o remount,rw,nodev,nosuid,noexec"

Comment: What would `grep shm /proc/*/mountinfo | sort -ut: -k2,2` print on that machine? Btw, you should leave `/dev/shm` alone. If you mount it `noexec`, you **break** `shm_open(3)` for **zero benefit**.

Comment: @uncle `/proc/1/mountinfo:22 17 0:18 / /dev/shm rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime - tmpfs tmpfs rw`.  The noexec was a finding from Tenable's CIS Linux Server Policy.

Comment: Please [do not cross-post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/64069/355310). For the record: the other copy is [on Super User](https://superuser.com/q/1679163/432690).